# Set PERM_WRITE_PROTECT on an SD card

Tags: storage, readonly, sd-card, removable-storage

From what I read [here](http://www.seanet.com/~karllunt/sdlocker.html) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital#Card_security) I gather that there is a bit on SD cards called PERM_WRITE_PROTECT that will allow me to make an SD card read only.  Is it possible to set this bit from Linux?  If so, how can I do so?

P.S. I realize that I could just mount it read only in fstab, but I am looking for a solution that will prevent it from being written to regardless of what device it is in, or what software is accessing it.

Comment: Many SD cards have a hardware 'read-only' switch.  Perhaps judicious use of some superglue?

Comment: From what I understand, the 'read-only' switch is only a suggestion to the reader.  Even if the 'read-only' switch is stuck in the read-only mode, I think it can still be written to with the right driver.

Comment: Interesting -- can you post a link?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sd_card#Card_security . The section on "Write-protect notch" mentions that it is only enforced by the reader, not the card.